# Ansible - Not able to add prefix 'ansible_hostname' to each item in an array when array already has variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to add 'ansible_hostname' as prefix to each item in an array but getting two different results.

- when the array is static without any variables then the hostname is getting added.
- when the array is having a variable declared then the fact 'ansible_hostname' is not getting resolved and is getting passed as a string.

I have array declared with variable, need help in passing the hostname without using loops.

Scenario 1:

```
  - name: test_array
    set_fact:
     test_array: ["This is test1 {{ansible_hostname}}", "This is test2"]     
  - set_fact: 
      test_fact: "{{ test_array | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', ' {{ansible_hostname}}, \\1') | join('\n') }}" 

output:
"test_fact": " {{ansible_hostname}}, This is test1 control\n {{ansible_hostname}}, This is test2"
```

Scenario 2:

```
 - name: test_array
    set_fact:
     test_array: ["This is test1", "This is test2"]    
  - set_fact: 
      test_fact: "{{ test_array | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', ' {{ansible_hostname}}, \\1') | join('\n') }}" 

output:
"test_fact": " host, This is test1 control\n host, This is test2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use jinja2 expansion inside jinja2 expansion. You have to concatenate the hostname with the rest of your regexp replacement with the `+` operator:

```yaml
- set_fact: 
    test_fact: "{{ test_array | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', ansible_hostname + ', \\1') | join('\n') }}"
```